# Scripts/plugins for skipping source file boilerplate in popular editors?

Tags: vim, emacs, editor, boilerplate

Most source files I edit have about 40 lines of boilerplate (license, etc) at the start of the file.  This is annoying me, because I have to scroll past it every time I load a file.

It seems like it wouldn't be too hard to make an editor automatically skip up to the first non-comment part of a file when it loads.  So: are there scripts or plugins for doing this with popular editors?  In the first instance I'm interested in vim and emacs, but any others would be interesting too.

Comment: I think this is answered for vim in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162617/how-can-i-automatically-add-some-skeleton-code-when-creating-a-new-file-with-vim/162671#162671

Comment: @Brian -- no, that question talks about how to automatically insert boilerplate.  This one is about how to skip past it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For GNU/Emacs, try putting the following code into your .emacs file:

```
(defun skip-file-initial-comment ()
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (while (looking-at (concat "\\s *" comment-start-skip))
    (forward-comment 1))
  (unless (= 0 (current-column))
    (beginning-of-line 2))
  (recenter 0))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'skip-file-initial-comment)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a plugin solution but it might help you nonetheless.

If you use `{` or `}` in normal mode in Vim it goes up or down one paragraph, i.e. it jumps to the next empty line.

So basically if you open a file with a big license text, most of the time it is considered as a single paragraph, so just typing `}` once should be enough to move to the interesting part of the code.

If you think `}` is too cumbersome to type, do not hesitate to remap it to a shortcut you are comfortable with.

It might not be the best solution for this specific case but it is handy command to scroll quickly in files.

Answer (score 1):

.vimrc:
set foldmethod=marker

files you're editing:

```
# {{{ Boilerplate
# stuff here is version blah blah and with more copyrights than you can ... blah blah
# }}}
```

Replace the # with whatever comment character(s) you've got in your programming language...

e.g. for C

```
/* {{{ Boilerplate stuff
 * stuff here is version blah blah and with more copyrights than you can ... blah blah
*/ }}}
```

OR

```
// {{{ Boilerplate stuff
// stuff here is version blah blah and with more copyrights than you can ... blah blah
// }}}
```

The key is the {{{ and }}} to "fold" sections of your code... you can hide this, and it'll appear as "Boilerplate stuff" or whatever comes after the opening "#{{{" brackets.

once a "fold" is closed you can open it by using "zo", and close it by "zc".
In VIM fashion, there are quite a few other options to folding, and you can check it out yourself in more details at: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Folding .