# Why does this uncommon VIM dot concatenation syntax work, while my common VIM syntax doesn't?

Tags: vim

Customizing my .vimrc I added template (skeleton) file support. This auto-command rule from a book didn't do anything (no errors nor templates):

`:autocmd BufNewFile * silent! Or $HOME/.vim/templates/%:e.tpl`

This non-%e-wildcard version produced an error:

`:autocmd BufNewFile *.html Or $HOME/.vim/templates/html.tpl`

```
"test.html" [New File]
Error detected while processing BufNewFile Auto commands for "*.html":
E492: Not an editor command: Or $HOME/.vim/templates/html.tpl
```

In another post user [orftz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162617/how-can-i-automatically-add-some-skeleton-code-when-creating-a-new-file-with-vim) (+1) showed us an uncommon syntax (what I'd recognize as PHP) using concatenation and double quotes.

`:autocmd BufNewFile * :silent! :exec ":0r " . $HOME . "/.vim/templates/" . &ft . ".tpl"`

What's wrong with my version of the common and why does the other version work (I don't see any quoting in other vim scripts like this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting or concatenation has nothing to do with this.

The original command most likely doesn't do anything because you forgot to declare the `Or` command. I obviously don't know what the book you referring to uses, but it most likely looks like `:command -nargs=1 Or read` for example.

Your second command fails because you also removed `silent!`. This statement will suppress all errors. Since you removed it, Vim will now warn you that `Or <argument>` is not known by the editor, so the missing `%:e` has nothing to with it.

If you want to know more about `%:e`, read http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#%:e - it will be substituted by the extension of the current file.

---

EDIT:
I see you were also confused by the [`.` operator](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expr-.) which can be used for string concatenation, and rightly so.

`.` simply means "concatenate the first string with the second", e.g. `let val2 = 'value ' . val1`.

The hairy thing is that Vim has a few commands which do concatenation themselves, `:execute`, `:echo` and `:echomsg` to just name a few. Such commands will automatically add in a space character if you pass it several expressions. The following commands should all be equivalent:

`:exec ":0r" $HOME . "/.vim/templates/" . &ft . ".tpl"
:exec ":0r " . $HOME . "/.vim/templates/" . &ft . ".tpl"
:exec (":0r " . $HOME . "/.vim/templates/" . &ft . ".tpl")
:exec ":0r" ($HOME . "/.vim/templates/" . &ft . ".tpl")`

This just goes to say that Vim script is all but pretty.