# What is the vim script syntax to test the value of a (boolean) option?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to add a conditional to my vimrc file testing if number (line numbers) option is set. I have :number added only with HTML file type,

```
:autocmd FileType html source $HOME/.vim/html_vimrc.vim

:if ('&number' == 0)  "IF number is off
: set spell           "turn on spell checker
:else                 "ELSE file type is HTML
:  set nospell        "turn spell checker off 
:endif
```

I've tried,

```
:if (&number == "number")

:if $number
```

I've tried with parentheses, quotes, no quotes. All my tests either set spell for all or none. I'm reading the [VIMDOCS](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_41.html#41.3) on conditionals, but I'm not getting something right and I can't find a similar example.

---

Update: In addition to testing Michael's code below, I've simplified the test with the following in vimrc:

```
:if exists("g:prog")
:  set number          "trying a different setting
:endif
```

And in the FileType loaded html_vimrc file I have,

```
"number                "turned this off 
:let g:prog=1
```

In this situation the test case of test.html the g:prog is set but "number" is not. In the test.vim case g:prog is not set and "number" is not. This seems to suggest there is some fundamental logic to how VIM handles loaded vimrc files that I am missing.

Answer (score 7):

Use `&number` to test a boolean, without quotes.

```
if (&number == 1)
```

Or more simply:

```
if (&number)
```

So your entire operation looks like:

```
if (&number == 0)  "IF number is off
 set spell           "turn on spell checker
else                 "ELSE file type is HTML
  set nospell        "turn spell checker off 
endif
```

Comment: I used the same syntax without success. In fact, in my delirium I typed == 1 to turn spell check on for html checked it, then checked it == 0. In my test case of `$vim test.html` and `$vim test`, the result was both files with or without (yes-yes or no-no). (The desired case is of course (yes-no)). %-(

Comment: ALSO, if it matters, I have another post about [vimrc file syntax weirdness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660627/why-does-this-uncommon-vim-dot-concatenation-syntax-work-while-my-common-vim-sy). They may be related?

Answer (score 1):

I simplified the situation to

```
:if exists("g:prog")
:  let g:ok_prog=1          "trying a different setting
:endif
```

Then I used `:let` to check if the variable is available to the different filetype use cases. This shows the variable from the .vimrc file loaded before the autoloaded g:var. (If someone else has a VIMDOCS reference that would be awesome). All of the conditionals fail because neither my :number option nor the g:var are loaded before the conditional fails.