# Automatic headers when opening a new python file with vim

Tags: python, vim, header, snipmate, autocmd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I automatically add some skeleton code when creating a new file with vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162617/how-can-i-automatically-add-some-skeleton-code-when-creating-a-new-file-with-vim)

I googled and searched on SO for a way to create automatic headers when creating a new python file. I was hoping to find something with snipMate but couldn't find anything.
I use [bash-suport](https://github.com/vim-scripts/bash-support.vim), [perl-support](https://github.com/vim-scripts/perl-support.vim) that provide this functionality and like it. If it can help I am also a user of [python-mode](https://github.com/klen/python-mode)

1. Is there a way to generate automatic headers with snipMate?
2. If not where can I find examples ?

I would like something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#===============================================================================
#
#         FILE: test.py
#
#        USAGE: ./test.py  
#
#  DESCRIPTION: 
#
#      OPTIONS: ---
# REQUIREMENTS: ---
#         BUGS: ---
#        NOTES: ---
#       AUTHOR: YOUR NAME (), 
# ORGANIZATION: 
#      VERSION: 1.0
#      CREATED: 09/12/2012 13:38:51
#     REVISION: ---
#===============================================================================


def main():
    """docstring for main"""
pass
```

Thanks a lot for reading

Comment: You could create a new Python snippet for snipmate called something like `py.snippet` and when you open a new file just type `py<tab>` to expand it.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162617/how-can-i-automatically-add-some-skeleton-code-when-creating-a-new-file-with-vim

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need Snipmate for that. Save your header to a file, then add the following to your `.vimrc`:

```
au BufNewFile *.py 0r /where/you/saved/your/header.template
```

This inserts your header automatically for every `.py` file.

If you want a header with variables (e.g. changing dates, revision numbers, filenames, etc.), [see this article](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/12/vi-and-vim-autocommand-3-steps-to-add-custom-header-to-your-file/) and [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Use_eval_to_create_dynamic_templates) for further help. But there are [other plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1160)(s) to help you out.