# In Vim, how can I create a dialogue that chooses from possible templates when a new file with certain extension is created?

Tags: templates, vim, ide

I'm aware from threads like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162617/how-can-i-automatically-add-some-skeleton-code-when-creating-a-new-file-with-vim) that one can have Vim insert some template code/preamble when a new file is opened, for example

```
autocmd BufNewFile *.tex 0r ~/skeleton.tex
```

but what if I want to choose from **multiple** templates? Is there a way I can use the `input()` command to select the filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out as I was writing the question, but wanted to make it available to future readers. Just put your templates whichever directory you find suitable, name them appropriately, and place in your `.vimrc`

```
autocmd BufNewFile *.<extension> execute "0r <directory>/".input("Template name: ").".<extension>"
```

...for example, I use `tex` for `<extension>`, the home directory `~` for `<directory>`, and the filenames `beamer.tex`, `basic.tex`, and `article.tex` for different LaTeX options. When I start a new file, I type (for example) "basic" when prompted, and it's loaded into the new empty file.